# Is script tag inside javascript string object currently forbidden?

Tags: javascript-objects, unexpected-token

I try this: `let textValue='<script></script>'`
but I get an error stated

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> [unexpected token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC8nH.jpg)

[Unterminated string literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFGgH.jpg)

I am wondering do javascript currently forbid the use of `<script>` tag for string object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let textValue='<script>content<\/script>';
console.log(textValue);
```